# What algorithm do the Compress and Uncompress functions use?

Tags: implementation-details, compression

[`Compress`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Compress.html) and [`Uncompress`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Uncompress.html) are used internally by *Mathematica* to compress things like 3D data in notebook files - data that I'd like to read independently. Does anyone have any idea if the compression algorithm is documented somewhere - Google reveals nothing of interest - or where I should start if I want to understand it?

Comment: The best I could find is: "The `Compress` function in *Mathematica* [...] is based on a mix of an LZ-like compression scheme and Huffman coding, called the Lempel-Ziv-Welch (LZW) algorithm; this same algorithm is at the base of the widespread gzip data compression software." (from [here](https://www.wolframscience.com/summerschool/2009/alumni/basile.html)). See also these questions as commentary: [`Compress` uses too much memory](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72344/27951) and [Is `Compress` compatible across version?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1415/27951)

Comment: The comment is incorrect (twice in a single sentence), in that LZW does not use Huffman coding, and that gzip does not use LZW to compress.

Comment: Also I found that `Compress[]` is currently using zlib compression, not LZW.

Comment: @MarkAdler +1 for your answer, but I think it is not the comment of MarcoB which is wrong but the content of what he is quoting. As the source seems to be from 2009 it might even be the case that it was correct back then. Have you checked whether this has changed from older versions? The real shame is that this is not more clearly documented...

Comment: I was referring to the comment within the web page linked by the comment. Sorry if it appears as if I impugned MarcoB. As for my comment on the comment in the web page linked by the comment, the two things noted as wrong are forever wrong. They are not time dependent. My second comment may be time dependent, hence my use of "currently". If someone has an example of old `Compress[]`'ed data, then I can look at what it was using then.

Comment: @MarkAdler: Sorry, I realized that my own comment was not very precise: the second part was meant to only address the part whether Compress is using zlib or LZW ("currently" is now recognized). What gzip internally uses and about the details of LZW I have no idea so cannot comment and am inclined to believe what you say is true (should be easy enough to check by those interested)...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is using the [zlib](http://zlib.net/) format followed by Base64 coding, and then preceding the resulting string with "1:". So to use it externally, you can strip the "1:", do Base64 decoding, and feed the result of that to a zlib decoder.

However what you get out may not be immediately useful. I compressed the result of `D[x^x, {x,9}]`, like one of the examples in the `Compress[]` documentation, and then decompressed (successfully) with zlib. I got what appears to be some sort of internal encoding. E.g. "!boRf" 0xa0, 0, 0, 0, "s", 0x04, 0, 0, 0, "Plusf", 0x03, ... (where the numbers are unprintable bytes).

If you want something interoperable, then use `"GZIP"` or `"BZIP2"` in `ImportString` and `ExportString`.  For example, using a 100,000,000 byte excerpt of English from Wikipedia:

```
ExportString[enwik8,"GZIP"]//StringLength
```

> ```
> 36548933
> ```

```
ExportString[enwik8,"BZIP2"]//StringLength
```

> ```
> 29008736
> ```

Then you will also get to control the encoding of the data into a string to be compressed. And you can decide whether or not to encode the compressed data into a printable form, or leave it as binary.

Comment: Thank you! Python's zlib module decompresses it just fine. The binary format (magic `!boRS`) is indeed another internal undocumented thing, and neither `Import[]` nor TrID have any idea what it is.

Comment: It should be noted that [Mark is in the best position to talk about zlib](https://www.zlib.net/zlib.html). ;)

Answer (score 21):

After a bit of poking around, it looks like the binary format is pretty simple to parse. [Mark Adler](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/94/mark-adler)'s answer is correct - the strings `Compress[]` returns are just zlib-compressed data. If you have Python installed, this function should take a compressed string and return the actual serialized bytes:

```
pyDecompress[c_] := StringDrop[StringDrop[StringTrim[RunProcess[{
  "python", "-c", 
  "import sys,zlib,base64; \
   print(zlib.decompress(base64.b64decode(sys.stdin.read().strip()[2:])))"
  }, "StandardOutput", c]], 2], -1]
```

Binary data starts with the header `!boR` (`21 62 6f 52`), followed by the serialized objects. There are apparently only eight types of objects that get serialized (unless I'm missing something):

- Machine-precision integers up to 32 bits: `i` followed by a reversed (that is, little-endian encoded) 32-bit value. The integer 192635 (`0x2f07b`), for instance, gets encoded as `7b f0 02 00`.
- Strings: `S` followed by a reversed 32-bit value for size and the actual ASCII string. 8-bit non-ASCII characters are encoded as `\\` followed by a three-digit number. It doesn't appear to be a Unicode offset (e.g. U+00BF encodes as 277, U+00C0 encodes as 300...). Everything else is encoded as UTF-16 in hexadecimal, preceded by `\\:` (e.g. U+057B becomes `\\:057B` and the astral plane character U+1F4A3 becomes `\\:D83D\\:DCA3`).
- Symbols: encoded just like strings, but with the lowercase prefix `s` instead of `S`.
- Arbitrary-precision integers: the actual base-10 digits encoded as a string, with the prefix `I`.
- Machine-precision real numbers: `r` followed by a reversed [IEEE binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) encoded floating point number. `1.0/3.0`, for instance, encodes to `55 55 55 55 55 55 d5 3f`.
- Arbitrary-precision real numbers: `R` followed by another string-style encoding: a reversed 32-bit length and the number in an expanded format. The number 13530274.2118781153, for instance, becomes the string `` 1.35302742118781153`17.131306598334415*^7 ``.
- Expressions: `f` followed by a reversed 32-bit value for the number of parts the expression has, the head of the expression encoded as a symbol, and the parts themselves. `A[1,2]`, for instance, would be encoded as `f<02 00 00 00>[A][3][12]`, with `[A]` being `s<01 00 00 00>A`, `[3]` being `i<03 00 00 00>` and `[12]` being `i<0c 00 00 00>`.
- Real matrices: a special encoding is used for large (>249 values) n-dimensional matrices (that is, lists or nested lists) of machine-precision real numbers. Starts with `e`, followed by a reversed 32-bit value for the n number, n more values for each dimension and then the binary64 encoded real numbers themselves, without any spacing or prefixes. There doesn't seem to be an equivalent for integers or arbitrary-precision reals.

**Update**: [here](https://xndc.github.io/uncompress/) is my attempt at a JavaScript parser for this format. Requires a fairly new browser.

Comment: I think all of the reversed quantities are not "reversed" as such, but just stored in little-endian format. Probably on other platforms a big-endian coding would have been used instead.

Comment: @OleksandrR. The format _should_ be platform-independent - as mentioned in the question, it's used in notebook files to store 3D graphics.

Comment: The "1:" may be a version and/or endianess indicator. Oleksandr is correct in that calling those "reversed" is just a personal bias on your part. They are in the correct and proper little-endian order. (Note that the use of "correct and proper" is a personal bias on _my_ part.)

Comment: There isn't a separate representation for integer arrays?  Can you try compressing a packed integer array, e.g. `RandomInteger[100, {10, 5}]`? This is interesting also because it is likely some sort of serialization of MathLink data (potentially even the exact same thing MathLink uses).  It would be interesting to investigate that too (i.e. capture what MathLink is sending through the network when using TCP/IP).

Comment: Here's a tool for decoding this data without python: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/75517/12  (function at the end of post)

Comment: @Szabolcs Even ridiculously huge integer arrays (just tried `RandomInteger[100, {250, 250}]`) serialize to nested lists.

Comment: I tried to capture some MathLink traffic with `tcpflow`. It's not the same as what you decode from `Compress`.

Comment: It's not uncompressing `Compress[-1]` correctly

Comment: Uh, my bad. It should work now.

Comment: How do I simulate Compress? I am trying
 base64.b64encode(zlib.compress('string'))

Comment: @HristoVrigazov That won't work; the first step is to convert whatever you're trying to compress into Mathematica's binary format.

Comment: How can I do that with Python?

Comment: @HristoVrigazov Presumably the same way you do it in any language: you look at documentation, experiment and figure it out. The answer you're commenting on literally tells you how the binary format works, and in case you understand JavaScript, my parser comes with [full source code](https://github.com/wickeda/uncompress). I'm not sure what else I can do to help.

Comment: When I try to decode a compressed string in python (using data = `data if isinstance(data, bytes) else data.encode('utf-8')
zlib.decompress(data)` ) I get the error `zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check`. I have tried with the leading `1:` and without it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Actually running the exact code in your answer in Mathematica I can't manage to correctly decode anything. Could you include an example.