# How to compress a string in Mathematica so that it can decompressed in python

Tags: python, compression

I need to compress a string into some format so that I can pass it along on the command line and avoid writing it to file (which would require locking files to prevent simultaneous writes so I prefer to pass it directly). I then need to decompress the string in Python. The standard `Compress` function seems like a good candidate as it indeed compresses strings into string without spaces. According to https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/104661/45020 I should be able to decode the string in python using `zlib`.

However, I cannot manage.

I tried with

```
import zlib
data = data if isinstance(data, bytes) else data.encode('utf-8')
data = base64.b64decode(data)
zlib.decompress(data)
```

where data is the string outputted by Compress in Mathematica with the leading `1:` removed as suggested in the linked post.

It decompressed without any error in python, but seems to be a meaningless string nothing like the original string that I put in. I guess that the standard Compress is no good to me in this situation?

How can I best compress a string in Mathematica in such a way that I can decompress it in Python.

---

Compressing using "GZIP" does not seem to work at all. I get an error

```
"File \!\(\"/tmp/m0000213298301.gz\"\) not found during Import"
```

---

Sorry about requiring no spaces. That was not actually important.

Comment: Did you notice that both answers mention that base64 encoding is also involved?

Comment: Thanks, I had read over that.

Comment: It did decompress now without errors, but the string is nothing close to what I originally put in? Any idea what I might still be doing wrong? Or would another compression method serve me better?

Comment: If I do `Compress["Hello, World!"]` then remove the initial `1:` with `StringTake[Compress["Hello, World!"], 3 ;;]` then I get `eJxTTMoPCuZlYGDwSM3JyddRCM8vyklRBAA//AYO` . From python I get `b'!boRS\r\x00\x00\x00Hello, World!'`. I suspect the initial junk is information Mathematica would use to determine the compressed object is a string when decompressing, since you can compress just about anything so it needs to know what type it is. The answer you linked actually mentions these mysterious bytes.

Comment: @flinty, thank you! When looking carefully I do see that some parts resemble the original. However in my case it is not as simple as it just being preceded by junk. The junk is everywhere. Things like `\\012\\011`.

Comment: Could you compress also with [BinarySerialize](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BinarySerialize.html) (using `PerformanceGoal -> "Size"`), then in python use the [WolframClientForPython](https://wolframresearch.github.io/WolframClientForPython/index.html) to extract it? The thing is that `BinarySerialize` performs better than `Compress`.

Comment: To take a different tackle, could you use [`URLEncode`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/URLEncode.html) which should also give a space-free string, then undo the character replacements in python? MMA has the complementary [`URLDecode`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/URLDecode.html) for that; perhaps Python has an equivalent readily available.

Comment: @MarcoB [Yes.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.unquote)

Answer (score 6):

I'm not familiar with your application nor your reason to remove spaces for passing arguments in the command-line interface. You will see two examples which in both of them a string successfully recived from Mathematica in python.

#### Without conversion:

Use python `sys` library to access command-line arguments passed to python with Mathematica `RunProcess` which will send values as argument without being worry about spaces:

```
message = "This is a sample text";

RunProcess[{"python", "-c", "import sys;print(sys.argv)", 
  message}, "StandardOutput"]

(*Out: "['-c', 'This is a sample text']" *)
```

In python use `sys.argv` to access the string you had sent as an argument.

#### With conversion:

I find out that Mathematica `ExportString[message, "Base64"]` will add `\n` to the end of the string, so before sending remove that:

````
message = "This is a sample text";

em = StringTake[ExportString[message, "Base64"], {1, -2}];

RunProcess[{"python", "-c", 
  "import base64;import sys;print(base64.b64decode(sys.argv[1]),end='')", 
  em}, "StandardOutput"]

RunProcess[{"python", "-c", 
  "import base64;print(base64.b64decode('" <> em <> 
   "'),end='')"}, "StandardOutput"]

(*Out 1: "b'This is a sample text'" *)

(*Out 2: "b'This is a sample text'" *)
```
````